# NodeJS setMaxListeners()

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, restart, forever

Having this problem for a while

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at Socket.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:160:15)
    at Socket.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:653:33)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.once (events.js:179:8)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:527:26)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: null
error: Forever restarting script for 6 time
```

So, what i did

```
var http = require('http').createServer(handler);
var port = 3002;
var ip = "192.168.10.4";
http.listen(port, ip); 
http.setMaxListeners(0);
```

On test server this error never appear(program running with nodemon, node), a tested with 30 sockets what was connected through network and they was using program, everything is fine. When i run my program on production server(forever) once in a day. Its not a problem, everyone gets his data back, but it is some service, and when a lot of users will use it(and they will, because its some solution for business) program will restart often. Have anyone ideas what it can be?

Thanks!

Comment: You `handler` function must be leaking memory by adding unneeded event listeners. Your current code doesn't produce such a warning.

Comment: My code is huge spagetti, and i cannot post everything here, main idea was only in that i use `setMaxListeners` for my emitter and it wont help